# How to show names over the image as in the Facebook android app?

Tags: android, image, android-layout

I seek for the same result as is shown on [this image]

[image]

Comment: @himanshu Nice edition. I din't know how to insert images. Now I know it. Thank you.

Comment: i m able to draw text over image using onDraw method.Now how to hide/show the text on touch ?

Answer (score 3):

Put the picture and the layout with text labels into one FrameLayout. Thus they will be one over the other.

Comment: i m able to draw text over image using onDraw method.Now how to hide/show the text on touch ?

Comment: Have I answered correctly? Please, mark the answer. Another question is not at all connected wish this one and should be asked separately. But firstly check if you have somewhere here the ready answer. You need 2 steps here - how put listener on your activity and how to hide/show textviews.

Comment: Actually my requirement was not only layout but to achieve the same functionality.

Comment: Reread the title of your question, please. Again, a new theme requires a new question.